# How do I force excel to display (potential) expressions as text, instead of attempt to evaluate them?

Tags: excel, expression, worksheet

I've got an excel worksheet that contains as cell values stuff like this

```
=-L
=-N
=-R
```

etc

Now, excel sees the "=" character and attempts to evaluate the expression. It cannot, and displays the following instead.

```
#NAME?
```

I would like the actual string "=-L" to be displayed instead.

I attempted to highlight the entire column and do

```
right click --> format cells --> Text --> OK
```

But the column didn't automatically update. I still see

```
#NAME?
```

where I should now be seeing

```
=-L
```

Now... if I double click the cell and then navigate elsewhere, it looks like the text value that is being displayed updates. However, I want the entire workbook to update so that I don't need to go through the hundreds of cells double clicking. I tried

```
F9
Shift + F9
ctrl + alt + Shift + F9
ctrl + alt + F9
```

etc.

Is there a way this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all. Replace = with '=.

OR

Under Formulas in the Ribbon, Under (technically over) Formula Auditing, select Show Formulas.  This applies to the entire worksheet.

Comment: There's no way to "reapply" the formatting once I have adjusted it on the column level?

Comment: So, I'd like to just do the one "cell reformatting" by right clicking the column once and applying the new formatting. I don't want to have to go through each cell and prepend a single quote. I suppose I could replace all, but I'd prefer to avoid manipulating the strings in the cells if possible.

Comment: That makes sense. I can't get that to work unless I format the cell as text before I enter the formula, but I'm sure someone else will have an answer more in line with what you're thinking.

Comment: Added an additional option to my original solution.

Comment: I like your second solution, it does what I need to do. Is there a way to just do this to a single column, and then save the file?

Comment: Save? Yes. Single column? Not with this method. It appears to be applied and saved at the worksheet level. (At least in Excel 2016)

Comment: This was good enough for what I need to do. This input is from a .csv file and as such there are no expressions in the entire file that need to be evaluated. I can just use the raw text. Thanks!